# Preventing <a> from inheriting text-align: justified?

Tags: html, css

I have the following sets of code:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav1" class="justify">
  <a href="../blah.php">blah</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../foo.php">foo</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../bar.php">bar</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../blahblah.php">blah blah</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.justify
{
   text-align:justify;
}
.justify:after
{
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;    
}
```

The problem is I want the links and |'s separated but the links that have multiple words I want a regular space between (I want "blah blah" to have a standard space, but the spaces in "blah | foo" to have the larger spaces). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Try

```
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
  .justify a {
    text-align: left;
  }
```

You target the parent and child seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but judging from your code, it might be simpler to do this, since you don't want the anchors justified.:

```
<div id="nav1">
  <div class="justify">Your text here.</div>
  <a href="../blah.php">blah</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../foo.php">foo</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../bar.php">bar</a> &#x7c; 
  <a href="../blahblah.php">blah blah</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `&nbsp;` to prevent the spaces I didn't want growing from growing.